# UIImageView orientation should be up, but is always LandscapeRight

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, orientation, landscape-portrait

I had already changed the imageOrientation for every image to .up as the following code describes:

```
if (imageProcessed!.imageOrientation != .up){
            print("imageProcessed != .up")
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageProcessed!.size, false, imageProcessed!.scale)
            imageProcessed!.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: imageProcessed!.size.width, height: imageProcessed!.size.height))
            imageProcessed = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            if(imageProcessed!.imageOrientation != .up){
                print("imageProcessed still != .up")
            }else if (imageProcessed!.imageOrientation == .up){
                print("imageProcessed == .up")
            }
        }

        circleView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        circleView.image = imageProcessed
```

But in the `UIImageView` **cameraView** the picture is always oriented to landscapeRight, although it says in the print command, that the imageOrientation is up.

For me it seems like the definition of the `UIImageView` orientation is that landscapeRight from the device equals up...
I really don't understand why every picture is displayed in this way.

Here are some examples:

[Image taken with orientation up shown in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b73B9.jpg)

[Image taken with orientation up shown in the UIImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgJsa.jpg)

Also pictures taken with orientation landscapeLeft are shown with orientation landscapeRight in the imageView.

But every picture with every orientation gets the orientation up from my code...

I want to have all pictures displayed with orientation "up" or "portrait-mode" and not landscapeRight. Could you tell me how to fix this problem?

Thank you all in advance!!